# Why is "xcodebuild: command not found" in this build script?

Tags: xcode, bash, sh, xcodebuild

Hi I have the following in the root of my xcode project:

```
#!/bin/bash
xcodebuild -scheme target1 clean;
xcodebuild -scheme target1 archive;
xcodebuild -scheme target2 clean;
xcodebuild -scheme target2 archive;
```

However, this only executes the first line `xcodebuild -scheme target1 clean;` and then yields

```
...
** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

xcodebuild: command not found
xcodebuild: command not found
xcodebuild: command not found
```

Disclaimer: I'm an absolute Mac OS X / Unix greenhorn.

**Edit**: Following kranteg's suggestion I added pwd to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd;
xcodebuild -scheme target1 clean;
pwd;
xcodebuild -scheme target1 archive;
pwd;
xcodebuild -scheme target2 clean;
pwd;
xcodebuild -scheme target2 archive;
pwd;
```

The output:

```
/Users/CKU/Programme/uraClient
=== CLEAN TARGET uraClient OF PROJECT uraClient WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

<... lots of compiler messages about the clean ...>

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

/Users/CKU/Programme/uraClient
xcodebuild: command not found
/Users/CKU/Programme/uraClient
xcodebuild: command not found
/Users/CKU/Programme/uraClient
xcodebuild: command not found
/Users/CKU/Programme/uraClient
```

**Edit 2**: Replacing the pwd with echo $PATH yields a better result, now the script performs the first three xcodebuild commands before failing. However, the PATH variable seems to be unaffected by xcodebuild:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools
=== CLEAN TARGET uraClient OF PROJECT uraClient WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

<... log messages ...>

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools
=== BUILD TARGET uraClient OF PROJECT uraClient WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

<... log messages ...>

** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **


The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    AnalyzeShallow uraClient/SQLiteLibrary/SQLiteManager.m
    AnalyzeShallow uraClient/URA/NSString+UrlEncoding.m
    AnalyzeShallow uraClient/Services/UraTripPredictionsProvider.m
    AnalyzeShallow uraClient/UtilityAppViewController/ViewController.m
    AnalyzeShallow uraClient/RNCryptor/RNDecryptor.m
    AnalyzeShallow uraClient/RNCryptor/RNEncryptor.m
    AnalyzeShallow uraClient/RNCryptor/RNOpenSSLCryptor.m
    AnalyzeShallow uraClient/RNCryptor/RNOpenSSLDecryptor.m
    AnalyzeShallow uraClient/RNCryptor/RNOpenSSLEncryptor.m
(9 commands with analyzer issues)
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools
=== CLEAN TARGET uraAseag OF PROJECT uraClient WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

<... log messages ..>

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools
xcodebuild: command not found
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: Can you launch `pwd` before and after you run this script ? xcodebuild seems to change the working directory.

Comment: Does not seem to be the case (see extended question).

Comment: Perhaps xcodebuild makes change to your PATH variable. Can you add echo $PATH to your script instead of pwd ?

Comment: Thanks for trying to debug this with me. :-) Although I cannot detect any changes in the PATH variable, it now actually runs the first three xcodebuild commands, but fails to perform the fourth.

Comment: It should work if you use absolute path, so use `/usr/bin/xcodebuild` in your script. But I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: You can pass multiple actions to single invocation: `clean archive`. What is the purpose of `;` at the end of the command?

Comment: @Opal: If I leave them away, the commands are interpreted as one single command, hence xcodebuild complains about an invalid argument "xcodebuild". Semicolons help, as do empty lines (maybe line endings are messed up by using TextEdit?).

Comment: @kranteg & Opal: I've found a working solution by combining your suggestions. Many Thanks!

Comment: Please, add your solution as an answer for users with same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of kranteg & Opal I've come up with a working solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme target1 clean archive;
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme target2 clean archive;
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme target3 clean archive;
<...>
```

Thanks again for the relentless community support, I would have given up otherwise :-)

Note: I've found that each scheme has a post-action step for the "Archive" action, that I had forgotten about:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "$ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH/$INSTALL_PATH/$WRAPPER_NAME" -o "${HOME}/Desktop/${PRODUCT_NAME}.ipa"
```

This automatically creates .ipa files for Ad-Hoc deployment. Maybe this interfered with the original build script by changing a working directory. However, I don't understand why that would not register with the `pwd` and `echo $PATH` logging.

Comment: Possible that after the command failed it performed a "cd" back to it's original directory before the printworkingdirectory command was called.

Answer (score 9):

`xcodebuild` command will not work when Command Lines Tools is not setup for xcode.

Make sure that latest command line tools are selected (Under `Xcode` > `Preferences` > `Locations`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've installed Xcode's command line tools. Go to the Xcode->Preferences... Command and look for the panel that lets you download additional packages and documentation. IIRC, the command line tools can be installed from there.

Comment: Hi, the command line tools are installed and working, otherwise the first clean would fail as well. In fact, all commands from the script work when entered manually in the terminal.